# Perl5Util Regex substitute

Tags: regex, string, replace, perl

I need some help to create/modify a regex to replace some strings. I've searched in other questions but without success.

I need to use Perl5Util substitute method to to this. I have the following code:

e.g.

```
String subQuery = "abc def ghi jkl";
subQuery = util.substitute("s/[ ]+/ " + "FOO" + ":/g", subQuery);
```

When I run the code I get:

abc FOO:def FOO:ghi FOO:jkl

This is Ok, but what I need is when I had a word/phrase in double quotes I'd get this

```
subQuery = "abc \"def ghi\" jkl";
```

output

abc FOO:"def ghi" FOO:jkl

I would appreciate any help.
Tks

Comment: Because I wouldn't like to modify the software implementation. But I'd accept your suggestion.

Comment: I guess a simple find `/[ ]+("[^"]*")?/` replace `FOO:$1` would work.

Comment: I need to replace the begining of the word with a String (JAVA), like my example above. But when I had double quotes I wouln't like the output be something like this

    abc "FOO:def FOO:ghi" FOO:jkl

but  this

    abc FOO:"def ghi" FOO:jkl

Comment: Yes, at the beginning of each word. But when the word is inside double quotes, the escape character (FOO:) be at the beginning of the double quotes, like this ( foo:"bla bla bla" ) and not ( foo:bla foo:bla foo:bla )

Comment: Please show me this simple example